# How to filter groups?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table like this:

```
Address                    AccountName        AccountId
-------------------------------------------------------
10007 Cougar Country       Smith              107
90026 Hunters Pond         Scott              106
10008 Indigo Run           Mary               108
70023 Kopplin Road         John               102
70023 Kopplin Road         John               103
70023 Kopplin Road         Peter              104
70023 Kopplin Road         Steve              105
70018 Oaks Drive           Joe                100
70018 Oaks Drive           Lisa               101
```

This is a result of joining two tables actually
with OrderBy Address. Table has records where 
Address and/or AccountName columns
can have identical values among multiple rows, 
while AccountId column would always be different.

How to get record groups where:
a) Address is same and AccountName is different 
b) Address is same and AccountName is same
Also number of records in a group > 1.
I need all fields from table.

Here is the output I need to have:

a) Address is same and AccountName is different:

```
Address                    AccountName         AccountId
-------------------------------------------------------
70023 Kopplin Road         Peter              104
70023 Kopplin Road         Steve              105
70018 Oaks Drive           Joe                100
70018 Oaks Drive           Lisa               101
```

b) Address is same and AccountName is same:

```
Address                    AccountName         AccountId
-------------------------------------------------------
70023 Kopplin Road         John               102
70023 Kopplin Road         John               103
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What have you tried? And what about things like 70023/ John where the only difference in those two rows is the AccountID? Is that one row in the output or two? It is not at all clear what you expect for output here. This would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I added ouput I need. I tried group by, thinking on row_number() with partition by, it can number records in each group. But how to get groups with number of records > 1 with that...

Comment: But wouldn't that address for 70023 still need to be in the output? It meets all the other criteria. So which value for AccountID would you want? Or do you want both?

Comment: AccountId is unique here. I do a web page where a user would select these AccountIds from a group and pass to SP. I just need a way to get groups from table. I used GroupBy Address

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this? It's certainly possible this could be improved if we knew more about your base query.

```
with data as (
    <yourQuery>
)
select
    case when count(*) over (partition by Address, AccountName) > 1
        then 'Same Address and AccountName' else 'Same Address only'
    end as Tag,
from data
where Address in (
    select Address
    from data
    group by Address
    having count(*) > 1
)
order by Tag, Address, AccountName
```

According to a comment on another answer it appears you may also want to handle repeated account names with different addresses. The question as posted describes something different. If you need this requirement to be incorporated into an answer you'll need to update the question accordingly.

*Edit per your comment*

```
with data as (
    <yourQuery>
), dups as (
    select *,
        case when count(*) over (partition by Address, AccountName) > 1
            then 'Same Address and AccountName' else 'Same Address only'
        end as Tag,
    from data
    where Address in (
        select Address
        from data
        group by Address
        having count(*) > 1
    )
)
select * from dups
where Tag = 'Same Address and AccountName' -- or 'Same Address only'
order by Tag, Address, AccountName
```

Comment: yes, I needed output of repeated account names too. count(*) over (partition by Address, AccountName) helped me here. I knew about row_number() we used in SPs for paging which Sean Lange kindly suggested. I finished my SP. It does a query which has group by Address or AccountName and has count(*) over.. in it's select list. Then I have another select over the first one, which filters out required records based on count(*) over. How can this Address In (group by Address) be improved ? We match records by a varchar field. It is not fast I guess ) I need an index on it ?

Comment: One you've got that "Tag" value you can split your results into two queries to return the results separately. If the query is slow then it makes sense to run it only once and grab the results to a temp table. Yeah, an index would help here.

Answer (score 0):

It still isn't totally clear what you want but this should get you close.

```
with SortedResults as
(
    select Address
        , AccountName
        , AccountId
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Address, AccountName order by AccountId) as RowNum
    from SomeTable
)
select *
from SortedResults
where RowNum > 1
```

Comment: This way I get all records starting from the second one from a group.\r\n 70023 Kopplin Road         John               102  (1)
70023 Kopplin Road         John               103  (2) I need all records in a group

Comment: You didn't have that in your expected output. Help me understand what you want. This shouldn't be this difficult and if you took the time to explain clearly what you wanted this would be solved already.

Comment: My table (this is actually a join of two tables, tbl_Account and tbl_Unit, first one has AccountId, AccountName, second one has Address) has value of Address and Name fields repeating among it's rows. 95% or rows have these two fields with unique values. I need to get records where these two fields have same values or when Address is same but  AccountName is different or AccountName is same but Address is different or just those records where no repeating values in those fields. Sorry if I explain my prob badly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Address varchar(150),AccountName varchar(50),AccountID varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('10007 Cougar Country','Smith','107'),
('90026 Hunters Pond'  ,'Scott','106'),
('10008 Indigo Run'    ,'Mary' ,'108'),
('70023 Kopplin Road'  ,'John' ,'102'),
('70023 Kopplin Road'  ,'John' ,'103'),
('70023 Kopplin Road'  ,'Peter','104'),
('70023 Kopplin Road'  ,'Steve','105'),
('70018 Oaks Drive'    ,'Joe'  ,'100'),
('70018 Oaks Drive'    ,'Lisa' ,'101')

;with cteBase as (Select *,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By Address,AccountName Order by AccountID) from @YourTable)
     ,cteLvl1 as (Select Address,GrpLvl1=IIF(count(*)>1,1,0) From cteBase Group by Address)
     ,cteLvl2 as (Select Address,AccountName,GrpLvl2=IIF(max(RowNr)>1,1,0) From cteBase Group by Address,AccountName)
Select Class=IIF(GrpLvl1+GrpLvl2=0,'None',IIF(GrpLvl1+GrpLvl2=1,'Group','Sub-Group'))
      ,A.Address
      ,A.AccountName
      ,A.AccountID
 From cteBase A
 Join cteLvl1 B on (A.Address=B.Address)
 Join cteLvl2 C on (A.Address=B.Address and A.AccountName=C.AccountName)
 Where GrpLvl1+GrpLvl2>=1
 Order By GrpLvl1+GrpLvl2,2,3,4
```

Returns

```
Class       Address             AccountName AccountID
Group       70018 Oaks Drive    Joe         100
Group       70018 Oaks Drive    Lisa        101
Group       70023 Kopplin Road  Peter       104
Group       70023 Kopplin Road  Steve       105

Sub-Group   70023 Kopplin Road  John        102
Sub-Group   70023 Kopplin Road  John        103
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is too complex for me :)